# Increase all items in an ArrayList<Integer> by a given amount with a lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

In my `Pixel` class I have the following code

```java
class Pixel {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ...
    public void brighten(int amount) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
        this.values.forEach((Integer value) -> newValues.add(value + amount));
        this.values = newValues;
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid creating `newValues` and increase the values in the `values` ArrayList directly in the lambda function?

Comment: Instances of  `Integer` are immutable. Thus, one has to create a new `List` with (possibly) new `Integer`-instances.

Comment: @Turing85 that doesn't avoid creating a new list

Comment: @tgdavies As I said before: creating a list is unavoidable, exept if one wants to delete elements from the old list one-by-one and re-inserting them.

Comment: What you could do is something like `values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).map(i -> i + amount).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `replaceAll` for that job:

```
values.replaceAll(i -> i + amount);
```